# Rails 6 Field Required but will not accept 0 or Null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have transferred my project from Rails 4 to Rails 6 and until recently, everything was working fine, but now when I go to update specific entries in my database, I get an error stating that "Boss must exist". The issue is there are a set of people that are the bosses but have no boss.

I have checked my schema and the field is not required. (boss_id)

person.rb

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :boss, class_name: 'Person'
    has_many :subordinates, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'boss_id'
end
```

form.html.erb

```
<fieldset>
        <label>
            Boss
            <%= f.select :boss_id, [[" ", :null], ["Name1", 1], ["Name2", 2], ... etc ... %>
        </label>
</fieldset>
```

adminnamespace/people_controller.rb

```
class NameSpace::PeopleController < NameSpaceController

  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def show
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    if @person.save
      flash[:notice] = "Person created successfully!"
      redirect_to namespace_person_path(@person)
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])

    if @person.update(person_params)
      redirect_to namespace_person_path(@person)
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    person = Person.find(params[:id])
    person.destroy
    redirect_to namespace_people_path
  end

  private
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(
      :uname, ... :boss_id) 
  end
end
```

If the boss_id is set to 0 or a number that does not have a corresponding record, I get this error. Do I need a work around or is there a way to make this work as it did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add `required: false` to `belongs_to` statement.

Eg:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :boss, class_name: 'Person', required: false
    has_many :subordinates, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'boss_id'
end
```